# How to merge a branch without also merging changes from previous branches

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I am kind of new to git and have a question regarding branching and merging those branches.

Let's say in my project repo I have 3 "main" branches: Alpha, Beta, Production.

Here is a scenario I am facing:

I currently work on the Alpha branch on my local machine. I create a new branch from Alpha, let's call it `feature/newFeature`. After creating the feature I commit and push the changes and then I merge `feature/newFeature` into the Alpha branch for QA to test. If QA approves, then it gets merged into Beta, then Production, etc.

Now, after `feature/newFeature` has been merged into Alpha (and not any other branch yet) I create another branch from Alpha, call it `fix/hotfix`. After fixing what needs to be fixed I merge this branch into Alpha as well.

But (and here is the problem I am facing), let's say that `fix/hotfix` has been tested and is working and can be merged into Beta, but `feature/newFeature` is still being tested on Alpha. If I try to merge the `fix/hotfix` branch into Beta, it will also merge changes from the `feature/newFeature` branch into Beta (which I obviously don't want because it is still being tested).

I understand why this happens, because when I merge `feature/newFeature` into Alpha and then create the `fix/hotfix` branch from Alpha after that merge, the `fix/hotfix` branch also contains the changes from the `feature/newFeature` branch.

My question is: Is there any way to do it in such a way that I can merge the `fix/hotfix` branch into Beta without it also merging the previous branches/changes that shouldn't be merged yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can always copy fix/hotfix branch and rebase it onto beta

```
git checkout fix/hotfix
git checkout -b fix/hotfix-copy
git rebase beta
```

That should leave you with the hotfix changes on beta branch. Then just merge the hotfix

Comment: Cherry-pick would be simpler, and accomplish the same thing (rebase is just automated cherry-picking, plus some branch name fiddling, and here we don't really want the branch-name-fiddling part). But either of these will work, yes.